# Solution to a vector recurrence equation

Tags: linear-algebra, symbolic, recursion

Suppose $n\ge1$ is fixed. Let $C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_n$ be given constants.
Consider the recurrence
$$
C_n[S_{1}^{(n)},S_{2}^{(n)},\ldots,S_{n-1}^{(n)}]=
\left[\binom{n}{1},\binom{n}{2},\ldots,\binom{n}{n-1}\right]
\begin{bmatrix}
S_{1}^{(1)}&0&0&0&\ldots&0\\
S_{1}^{(2)}&S_{2}^{(2)}&0&0&\dots&0\\
S_{1}^{(3)}&S_{2}^{(3)}&S_{3}^{(3)}&0&\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
S_{1}^{(n-1)}&S_{2}^{(n-1)}&S_{3}^{(n-1)}&S_{4}^{(n-1)}&\ldots&S_{n-1}^{(n-1)}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $S_{i}^{(i)}=1/C_i$ for any $i\ge1$. So basically the diagonal elements of the matrix on the right are known.

One by one, one can recover $S_{n-1}^{(n)}$, and then $S_{n-2}^{(n)}$, and then $S_{n-3}^{(n)}$, and all the way back to $S_{1}^{(n)}$.  For example, one finds that
$$S_{n-1}^{(n)}
=
\dfrac{\binom{n}{1}}{C_n C_{n-1}},
\\
S_{n-2}^{(n)}
=
\dfrac{\binom{n}{2}}{C_{n-2}C_n}+\dfrac{\binom{n}{1}\binom{n-1}{1}}{C_{n-2}C_{n-1}C_n},
\\
S_{n-3}^{(n)}
=
\dfrac{\binom{n}{3}}{C_{n-3}C_n}+\dfrac{\binom{n}{2}\binom{n-2}{1}}{C_{n-3}C_{n-2}C_n}+\dfrac{\binom{n}{1}\binom{n-1}{2}}{C_{n-3}C_{n-1}C_n}+\dfrac{\binom{n}{1}\binom{n-1}{1}\binom{n-2}{1}}{C_{n-3}C_{n-2}C_{n-1}C_n},
$$
and so on.

I wonder whether it's possible to recover the pattern behind the expressions on the right above. In other words, whether it's possible to find a compact closed-form formula  for $S_{i}^{(n)}$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n-1$ and a fixed $n\ge1$.